# How to create BinaryArray in VbScript?

Tags: vbscript, binary

I want to manually create a binary script and then save it as binary file.

I want to append all of the following bytes and create a binary file out of them.

```
&HF0
&HF1
&HF2
```

I want to able to do something like this :

```
Dim generateData(3) As Byte
generateData(0) = &HFF
generateData(1) = &HFE
generateData(2) = &HFC
```

But obviously **As Byte** doesn't work on Vbscript. I do use the following function to write binary array to disk (at least I'll when I able to create a binary array)

```
Function SaveBinaryData(FileName, ByteArray)
  Const adTypeBinary = 1
  Const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2

  'Create Stream object
  Dim BinaryStream
  Set BinaryStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

  'Specify stream type - we want To save binary data.
  BinaryStream.Type = adTypeBinary

  'Open the stream And write binary data To the object
  BinaryStream.Open
  BinaryStream.Write ByteArray

  'Save binary data To disk
  BinaryStream.SaveToFile FileName, adSaveCreateOverWrite
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen something along these lines used:

```
Sub WriteBinary(FileName, Buf)  

    Dim I, aBuf, Size, bStream  

    Size = UBound(Buf): ReDim aBuf(Size \ 2)  

    For I = 0 To Size - 1 Step 2  

        aBuf(I \ 2) = ChrW(Buf(I + 1) * 256 + Buf(I))  

    Next  

    If I = Size Then aBuf(I \ 2) = ChrW(Buf(I))  

    aBuf=Join(aBuf, "")  

    Set bStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")  

    bStream.Type = 1: bStream.Open  

    With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")  

        .Type = 2 : .Open: .WriteText aBuf  

        .Position = 2: .CopyTo bStream: .Close  

    End With  

    bStream.SaveToFile FileName, 2: bStream.Close  

    Set bStream = Nothing  

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

The using a TypeText-ADODB.Stream to write a file and read it back as TypeBinary-ADODB.Stream  is a Common solution, but it requires a Temp file and Text safe bytes. There is a better way using **System.IO.MemoryStream**

```
'Dim generateData(3) As Byte
Dim generateData(3) 
generateData(0) = &HFF
generateData(1) = &HFE
generateData(2) = &HFC

Set mem = CreateObject("System.IO.MemoryStream")
mem.SetLength(0)
For Each B in generateData 
   mem.WriteByte (B)
Next
generateData_as_ByteArray = mem.ToArray()  'Returns a VB Style, "Byte()"   [Byte Array]
```

Or in the Question's Original Example

```
Function SaveBinaryData(FileName, VbByteArray)
  Const adTypeBinary = 1
  Const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2

  'Create Stream object
  Dim BinaryStream
  Set BinaryStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

  'Specify stream type - we want To save binary data.
  BinaryStream.Type = adTypeBinary

  'Open the stream And write binary data To the object
  BinaryStream.Open

  'Covert VBS Array of Byte Values; TypeName "Variant()"
  'to a true Byte Array; TypeName "Byte()"
  Set mem = CreateObject("System.IO.MemoryStream")
  mem.SetLength(0)
  For Each B in VbByteArray
     mem.WriteByte (B)
  Next
  ByteArray = mem.ToArray() 'Output as Btye()

  'Works
  BinaryStream.Write ByteArray

  'Save binary data To disk
  BinaryStream.SaveToFile FileName, adSaveCreateOverWrite
End Function
```

An **ADODB.Stream** (in Binary Mode) only lets you add Arrays of Bytes, but the closely related **System.IO.MemoryStream** also lets you add Data as Arrays of Bytes, however has the *.WriteByte* function which takes just a single byte, which VBS can do.

**System.IO.MemoryStream**'s *.ToArray* returns a ByteArray the same as *.read* does with **ADODB.Stream**; both of which is the type "byte()" that **ADODB.Stream** *.Write* wants.

Comment: It works for me! I used to get "byte()" by using `ADODB.Stream` to read a prepared file which contains 256 bytes from 0x00 to 0xFF.