# How to declare ASP classic constants to a data type?

Tags: asp-classic

In asp classic and vbscript, you can declare a Const with a hexidecial value, and a date type value:

```
 Const C_LIGHTCYAN = &hCCFFEE
 Const C_STARTDATE = #1 JAN 2000#
```

But how can I declare currency, single or doubles data types?

```
 Const C_LONG = 1024 '# I want this to be a LONG, not an INT!
```

*I'm sure I've seen something like `Const C_LNG = L12345` or some other prefix/suffix combination for longs or doubles but can't find the source now*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't declare variables with data types in ASP just set the value in decleration, that should work *fingers crossed*.

<strike>I don't think there is currency type anyway.</strike> For double you can 1.00 etc.

Comment: There are currency data types: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/9e7a57cf(VS.85,loband).aspx

I like "fingers crossed".  I've gotfar too used to that that now...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [CLng function for VBScript](http://devguru.com/technologies/vbscript/13908.asp).  But since you can't declare use a function for a constant declaration, and you can't re-assign to a constant, do you really have to use constants here?

Comment: The linked URL is dead. That's not cool. https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI

Answer (score 0):

While you can't **declare** data types in Windows Scripting (VBScript, ASP), you can **assign** a variable to become a type, then verify that variable's type. VBScript provides no type protections, so you're allowed to reassign a declared variable to a different type. This *loose typing* strategy is one root of problems.

```vb
Dim textVariable : textVariable = "Hello World!"
WScript.Echo TypeName(textVariable)
' Returns Text

Dim integerVariable : integerVariable = 6
WScript.Echo TypeName(integerVariable)
' Returns Integer

Dim objectVariable : set objectVariable = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
WScript.Echo TypeName(objectVariable)
' Returns Object
```

Some types require some brute force and trickery. [The `binary` datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64616421/3133043) is one example.

```vb
Dim generateData(1) : generateData(0) = &HFF
Dim mem : Set mem = CreateObject("System.IO.MemoryStream")
mem.SetLength(0)
mem.WriteByte (generateData(0))
Dim byteArray : byteArray = mem.ToArray()
'Returns a VB Style, "Byte()"   [Byte Array]
```