# How can I write binary data to disk in VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, binary

I have a binary string that I need to write to a file. I have a feeling that this *should* be a simple procedure, but then again, VBScript. The `FileSystemObject` is of no help, since it munges the data. The `Stream` object looks promising, with it's `adBinaryMode` and its `Write` method, but the `Write` method requires a byte array and won't seem to accept a variant array instead. Since VBScript arrays are *all* variant arrays, this seems problematic.

So, how do I just write the data to a file?

EDIT: I should add that the whole thing has to be VBScript. No extra components. Sorry, I don't like it either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's also possible with the ordinary `FileSystemObject`, here is code I'm using in custom upload script that I wrote long time ago using code I found online that converts binary string to ASCII:

```
Set objFSO = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("file path here")
objFile.Write(RSBinaryToString(strBinaryContents))
objFile.Close
Set objFile=Nothing
Set objFSO=Nothing

Private Function RSBinaryToString(xBinary)
    'Antonin Foller, http://www.motobit.com
    'RSBinaryToString converts binary data (VT_UI1 | VT_ARRAY Or MultiByte string)
    'to a string (BSTR) using ADO recordset

    Dim Binary
    'MultiByte data must be converted To VT_UI1 | VT_ARRAY first.
    If vartype(xBinary)=8 Then Binary = MultiByteToBinary(xBinary) Else Binary = xBinary

    Dim RS, LBinary
    Const adLongVarChar = 201
    Set RS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    LBinary = LenB(Binary)

    If LBinary>0 Then
        RS.Fields.Append "mBinary", adLongVarChar, LBinary
        RS.Open
        RS.AddNew
        RS("mBinary").AppendChunk Binary 
        RS.Update
        RSBinaryToString = RS("mBinary")
    Else  
        RSBinaryToString = ""
    End If
End Function

Function MultiByteToBinary(MultiByte)
    '© 2000 Antonin Foller, http://www.motobit.com
    ' MultiByteToBinary converts multibyte string To real binary data (VT_UI1 | VT_ARRAY)
    ' Using recordset
    Dim RS, LMultiByte, Binary
    Const adLongVarBinary = 205
    Set RS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    LMultiByte = LenB(MultiByte)
    If LMultiByte>0 Then
        RS.Fields.Append "mBinary", adLongVarBinary, LMultiByte
        RS.Open
        RS.AddNew
        RS("mBinary").AppendChunk MultiByte & ChrB(0)
        RS.Update
        Binary = RS("mBinary").GetChunk(LMultiByte)
    End If
    MultiByteToBinary = Binary
End Function
```

Comment: I've been butting my head against the wall over this whole ASP file upload issue, this is finally something that just works :-). I can't believe that something this essential needs that such an amount of third party fiddling :-/. Thank you veeeeery much!!!!

Comment: @mfeineis lol, glad this oooold code was of such a great help! :)

Comment: Awesome, right now i have to fight with this ancient stuff also and this seems to be the only solution that just works after endless hours of fiddling / testing / searching.

Comment: The question is asking to write a binary file in VBS without external downloads.

Comment: @Zimba true, and my answer is pure VBScript. No external downloads. Copy and paste, and it works. Cheers.

Comment: @ShadowWizardisEarForYou: isn't `ADODB` external?

Comment: @Zimba no it's not. External libraries are stuff like upload via third party, e.g. the component mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9805661/asp-upload-component-classic-asp). It's compiled into a DLL and you have no control over it.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.motobit.com/tips/detpg_read-write-binary-files/) are several options. The most interesting variant described there converts the binary data to a string with the help of a custom function [BinaryToString](http://www.motobit.com/tips/detpg_binarytostring/).

Comment: The question is asking to write binary data to disk (to create a file)

Answer (score 2):

Writing to a binary file in VBScript is simple but requires you to write one byte at a time. As a demonstration, here is a simple script that creates a single pixel GIF file. The resulting file has exactly the binary content written to it, nothing more, and is a valid GIF file.

```
Dim GifFile : Set GifFile = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile("SinglePixel.gif")

With GifFile
    .write chr(&h47) 'GIF87a
    .write chr(&h49)
    .write chr(&h46)
    .write chr(&h38)
    .write chr(&h37)
    .write chr(&h61)
    .write chr(&h01) 'Width
    .write chr(&h00)
    .write chr(&h01) 'Height
    .write chr(&h00)
    .write chr(&h80) 'Use global color map
    .write chr(&h00) 'Background
    .write chr(&h00) 'End of header
    .write chr(&h00) 'Color map color #1 in RGB
    .write chr(&h00)
    .write chr(&h00)
    .write chr(&hFF) 'Color map color #2 in RGB
    .write chr(&hFF)
    .write chr(&hFF)
    .write chr(&h2C) 'Image descriptor
    .write chr(&h00) 'Left
    .write chr(&h00)
    .write chr(&h00) 'Top
    .write chr(&h00)
    .write chr(&h01) 'Width
    .write chr(&h00)
    .write chr(&h01) 'Height
    .write chr(&h00)
    .write chr(&h40) 'Use global color map / seq order / 1 bit per pixel
    .write chr(&h02) 'Code size
    .write chr(&h02) 'Blok byte count
    .write chr(&h44) 'LZW data
    .write chr(&h01)
    .write chr(&h00) 'Terminate data stream
    .write chr(&h3B) 'Gif terminator
End With

GifFile.Close
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using `System.IO.MemoryStream` to get "bytes" which is required by `ADODB.Stream`.

```vb
Function ArrToBytes(byteArr)
    dim mem,i,v
    Set mem = Server.CreateObject("System.IO.MemoryStream")
    mem.SetLength 0
    For Each v in byteArr 
        mem.WriteByte v
    Next
    ArrToBytes = mem.ToArray()
    Set mem = Nothing
End Function

dim stm
Set stm = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
With stm
    .Type = 1
    .Open
    .Write ArrToBytes(Array(&H80, &H81))
    .Write ArrToBytes(Array(&H82, &H83, &H84, &H85))
    .SaveToFile Server.MapPath("test.bin"), 2
    .Close
End With
Set stm = Nothing
```

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64616421/988089).

Answer (score 0):

To write a (hex encoded) binary string to file with `FileSystemObject`:

```
Dim File : Set File = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile("Binary.gif")

data = "47 49 46 38 37 61 07 00 07 00 80 F0 00 FF 00 00 00 FF FF 2C 00 00 00 00 07 00 07 00 40 02 02 44 01 00 3B"
data = Split (data)

for each x in data
File.write chr("&H" & x)
next

File.Close
```