# ASP Upload Component - Classic ASP

Tags: file-upload, asp-classic

I have just moved a site from a dedicated server to a GoDaddy shared hosting account, and have just encountered loads of problems! One being with ASP Upload.

In Classic ASP, this is what I would normally do to upload files to my folder:

```
Set upload = Server.CreateObject("Persits.Upload")
uploadPath = Server.MapPath("../../files/photos/"&token_&"/")
upload.IgnoreNoPost = True
upload.Save(uploadPath)
Set upload = Nothing
```

But since moving to GoDaddy, I get this nasty message:

```
This feature has been disabled by the system administrator. Use SaveVirtual instead.
```

I went on to ASP Upload's website documentation and I could not find **SaveVirtual**, only **SaveAsVirtual** which is where I have become unstuck.

I tried using SaveAsVirtual but it threw an error stating that I was using a physical path and I should be using a virtual path! I really don't understand this and was hoping that somebody could put me straight. My website is now deemed broken and is offline, please help.

This is what I tried before the physical/virtual path error:

```
Set upload = Server.CreateObject("Persits.Upload")
uploadPath = Server.MapPath("../../files/photos/"&token_&"/")
upload.IgnoreNoPost = True
upload.SaveAsVirtual(uploadPath)
Set upload = Nothing
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://www.aspupload.com/object_upload.html#SaveVirtual), the method is named `SaveVirtual`. It does the `Server.MapPath` conversion for you.

So, try:

```
Set upload = Server.CreateObject("Persits.Upload")
uploadPath = "../../files/photos/"&token_&"/"
upload.IgnoreNoPost = True
upload.SaveVirtual(uploadPath)
Set upload = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

You already set a folder path to upload not need use like this "server.mappath"

please use below of code.

```
Set Upload = Server.CreateObject("Persits.Upload" ) 

Upload.SetMaxSize 10000000 ' Maksimum dosya büyüklüğü Byte cinsinden 
Upload.OverwriteFiles = True 

Path = "../../duyurular/"
Count = Upload.SaveAsVirtual(Path)
```

Comment: You're a bit late my friend. This question was answered 20 months ago. I haven't used ASP Classic since this question either. It may be a greater help if you answer recent questions that haven't been accepted yet.

Answer (score 0):

for godaddy you have to go in and change the server folder permission to read/write.  Otherwise you get that error message.

Answer (score 0):

well I also get encounter with this problem, I just changed the folder privileges from **Go-daddy** Hosting server so Any one can read or Write file from specific location

Many Thanks
[Ahsan Aziz Abbasi](http://www.marksykov.com)