# Using Outlook 2016 VBA, Retain Attachment When Sending using SMTP/CDO

Tags: vba, outlook, cdo.message

I would like to avoid saving the attachment from the original Outlook message to a local drive and then reattach it to the SMTP message.  The message body is recreated for the SMTP message, which works fine.

```
Sub ForwardEmail(myEmail As Outlook.MailItem) 'subroutine called from Outlook rule, when new incoming email message arrives
Const PR_SMTP_ADDRESS As String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0076001E"
Set objSMTPMail = CreateObject("CDO.Message") 'needed to send SMTP mail
Set objConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration") 'needed for SMTP configuration

Set objFlds = objConf.Fields 'used for SMTP configuration

'Set various parameters and properties of CDO object

objFlds.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2     
objFlds.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtpout.test.com" 'define SMTP server
objFlds.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25 'default port for email

objFlds.Update

objSMTPMail.Configuration = objConf

If myEmail.SenderEmailType = "EX" Then
  objSMTPMail.From = myEmail.Sender.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
Else
  objSMTPMail.From = myEmail.SenderEmailAddress 'takes email address from   the original email and uses it in the new SMTP email
 objAttachments = myEmail.Attachments  ' I believe this is how to get the attachments

End If

objSMTPMail.Subject = myEmail.Subject 'use the subject from the original email message for the SMTP message
objSMTPMail.HTMLBody = myEmail.HTMLBody 'myEmail.HTMLBody is necessary to retain Electronic Inquiry Form formatting
objSMTPMail.To = "nobody@test.com"
objSMTPMail.AddAttachment objAttachments ' tried to add attachment
'send the SMTP message via the SMTP server
objSMTPMail.Send




'Set all objects to nothing after sending the email

Set objFlds = Nothing
Set objConf = Nothing
Set objSMTPMail = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: The following lines in the code are what I thought would work, but do not.  objAttachments = myEmail.Attachments   and then SMTPMail.AddAttachment objAttachments    It only attaches an empty BIN file (file extension is BIN).

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29232075/set-binary-base64-data-as-attachment-in-vb-script-cdo-message) (it's ASP, but should give the gist) for an idea of how to add an attachment that isn't from a file.  Note that you'll need to find a Base64 encoder (or write one - it isn't hard).

Comment: @user9308240 I don't see `objAttachments` declared anywhere. If it should be an object reference, you might need to 1. `Dim` it as an object and 2. you might need to change `objAttachments = myEmail.Attachments` to `Set objAttachments = myEmail.Attachments`. To avoid these kinds of errors, putting `Option Explicit` at the top of the module/before your code can help.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I will do some testing this evening and post an update by tomorrow morning.  If it matters, the attachments could be anything such as a ODF, DOCX, JPEG, etc.  I have worked with VBA very little and definitely not with Outlook , so it is new territory for me.

Comment: I found it easiest to save the file(s) locally and then reattach them to the SMTP message.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.  It works for my situation.

```
Sub ForwardEmail(myEmail As Outlook.MailItem) 'subroutine called from Outlook rule, when new incoming email message arrives

On Error GoTo Resetvar
Set objSMTPMail = CreateObject("CDO.Message") 'needed to send SMTP mail
Set objConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration") 'needed for SMTP configuration

Set objFlds = objConf.Fields 'used for SMTP configuration

'Set various parameters and properties of CDO object

objFlds.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 'cdoSendUsingPort
objFlds.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtpout.test.com" 'define SMTP server
objFlds.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25 'default port for email

objFlds.Update

objSMTPMail.Configuration = objConf

'EX value is an Exchange mailbox locally
If myEmail.SenderEmailType = "EX" Then
    objSMTPMail.From = myEmail.Sender.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
Else
    objSMTPMail.From = myEmail.SenderEmailAddress 'takes email address from the original email and uses it in the new SMTP email
End If
Dim i As Integer
i = -1
Dim arrAtmt() As String
Dim FileName As String
For Each Atmt In myEmail.Attachments
    FileName = "C:\temp\" & myEmail.EntryID & "." & Atmt.FileName
    Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName
    i = i + 1
    ReDim Preserve arrAtmt(i)
    arrAtmt(i) = FileName
Next Atmt

    objSMTPMail.Subject = myEmail.Subject 'use the subject from the original email message for the SMTP message
    objSMTPMail.HTMLBody = myEmail.HTMLBody 'myEmail.HTMLBody is necessary to retain Electronic Inquiry Form formatting
    objSMTPMail.To = "mary@test.com"

    If i > -1 Then
        For counter = 0 To i
            objSMTPMail.AddAttachment arrAtmt(counter)
        Next
    End If
    objSMTPMail.Send

Erase arrAtmt

Resetvar:

Set objFlds = Nothing
Set objConf = Nothing
Set objSMTPMail = Nothing

End Sub
```