# WinHttp.WinHttpRequest adding to the content-type

Tags: vba, ms-access, winhttp, winhttprequest

I'm trying to make a request to kigo's api using vba WinHttp.WinHttpRequest,
i was able to send a request, but WinHttpRequest changes the content-type adding
Charset=UTF-8 when it sends the request, with that kigo's api returns 415 error.

I set the content-type like this

```
web_Http.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
```

but when the i look at the request in Wireshark the content-type is like this

```
Content-Type: application/json; Charset=UTF-8
```

Any ideas?

I found [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/52fca0ca-858d-4c9a-9daa-e693a290f40d/how-do-i-prevent-winhttprequest-from-automatically-appending-charsetutf8-to-contenttype?forum=windowscompatibility), that is similar to my problem but i dont understand the solution.

Comment: What charset are they expecting? have you tried specifying it in your `Content-Type` string?

Comment: The content-type should be only application/json without anything else, if the content-type have anything beyond application/json i get an error. Yes i tried to specify  the Content-Type string. This happens after i setup the request.

Comment: Try ending your string with a semicolon. Any luck?

Comment: I tried, no luck. my problem is similar to this one [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/52fca0ca-858d-4c9a-9daa-e693a290f40d/how-do-i-prevent-winhttprequest-from-automatically-appending-charsetutf8-to-contenttype?forum=windowscompatibility)

Comment: Hmm.. that's not looking good.. is VBA your only option? Best of luck!

Comment: Unfortunately yes, thanks

Comment: Have you tried using MSXML2.XMLHTTP instead of winhttp.WinHttpRequest?

Comment: @gofr1 thanks man, i was able to make the request with  MSXML2.XMLHTTP

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm running into this problem, as well. It seems to be limited to the [`WinHttp.WinHttpRequest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384106(v=vs.85).aspx) COM interface. There are a couple of different options to resolve this.

After some digging, I found [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.winhttp/cALn-YvD8Qw) from a Microsoft employee. It gives a clear explanation and recommends sending in a binary array.

> If you are POSTing a string using the WinHttpRequest object, you cannot
>   override how it encodes the string for transmission. The WinHttpRequest
>   object will always convert the Unicode string to UTF-8.
>
> However, note that a Unicode string that contains only 7-bit
>   LATIN-1/ISO-8859-1 characters will remain unchanged when encoded as UTF-8
>   ;-)   In such cases, the WinHttpRequest object does not append a
>   "Charset=UTF-8" attribute to your Content-Type header. (And I would think
>   that the server would assume that the POST data is ISO-8859-1.)
>
> So, if the XML text data that you are POSTing contains LATIN-1 alphanumeric
>   or punctuation character codes (each less than decimal 128), then all you
>   should have to do is specify the "ISO-8859-1" charset in your Content-Type
>   header:
>
> `WinHttpReq.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/xml;Charset=ISO-8859-1"`
>
> However, if your POST data contains 8-bit characters, then you cannot supply
>   the data as a string to the Send method. In order to avoid the UTF-8
>   conversion, your application must convert the string into a byte array, and
>   supply that instead. The WinHttpRequest object will not attempt any data
>   conversion on a byte array.
>
> Regards,
>
> Stephen Sulzer
>
> Microsoft Corporation

---

A second option, other than sending in a binary array, is to switch to [`Msxml2.XMLHTTP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535874(v=vs.85).aspx) or [`Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762278(v=vs.85).aspx). Neither of these mangle the [`Content-Type`](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/4_Content-Type.html) header. Luckily, when `WinHttp.WinHttpRequest` was created, Microsoft intentionally used `Msxml2.XMLHTTP` as a template for the interface. So, it is fairly trivial to convert the code.

Also, the `Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP` COM interface [uses WinHTTP internally](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/290761). So, while you are losing access to some of the features that are exclusive to `WinHttp.WinHttpRequest`, both use the same backend.

---

The third option is to use [`ADODB.Stream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It allows you to work with an [`IStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380034), which isn't something you can normally do from VBA. The sample code below is based on the answer on the question ["How to create BinaryArray in VbScript?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548102/how-to-create-binaryarray-in-vbscript).

```
' Create a Binary Stream
Set objStreamBinary = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")  
objStreamBinary.Type = 1
objStreamBinary.Open  

' Create a Text Stream
Set objStreamText = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")  
objStreamText.Type = 2
objStreamText.Open
' Copy the POST data to the Text Stream
objStreamText.WriteText strRequest  
objStreamText.Position = 2
' Copy the Text Stream Contents to the Binary Stream
objStreamText.CopyTo objStreamBinary
objStreamText.Close  

' Read the contents of the Binary Stream
' and send it to the WinHttpRequest object
web_Http.Send objStreamBinary.Read(-1)
```

Comment: `Since VBA doesn't have strongly typed arrays` - VBA has strongly typed arrays. VBScript is a different language.

Comment: @GSerg thanks. I wasn't aware. I have removed that sentence from my answer.

Comment: Just changing to Set objHTTP = CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP") worked for me.

Comment: The issue is that adding ***ANY*** `Charset` to the `Content-Type` runs afoul of a bug in Apahe and Azure that blocks the request because it thinks it's malformed.