# How to remove Charset from Content-Type when using WinHTTP?

Tags: http, content-type, winhttp, winhttprequest

When you use the [**WinHttpRequest**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/winhttprequest) object to `POST` data to a server:

```
IWinHttpRequest http = CoWinHttpRequest.Create();
http.Open("POST", "http://example.contoso.com/api/v1/grobber", false);
http.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=MultipartBoundary");
http.Send(formData);
```

the WinHTTP component will silenty change your `Content-Type` header; by appending `Charset`:

- **Before**: `Content-Type=multipart/form-data;boundary=MultipartBoundary`
- **After**: `Content-Type-multipart/form-data;boundary=MultipartBoundary;Charset=UTF-8`

This runs afoul of a [bug in Apache](https://archive.ph/POkdm) where it will [not recognize any `Content-Type` header that contains `Charset`.](https://archive.ph/ie87l)

One suggestion online was to try to proactively add the `Charset` yourself, and add it earlier in the `Content-Type` string, so that maybe Apache will accept it:

```
http.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "Charset=UTF-8;multipart/form-data;boundary=MultipartBoundary");
```

except it doesn't work. It goes out to the server with `Charset` in the first position; but Apache still chokes on it.

How can I suppress WinHTTP from automatically adding a `Charset` to my `Content-Type`?

### Bonus Reading

- MSDN Forums: [How to remove "charset=UTF-8" from Content-Type](https://archive.ph/ie87l)
- MSDN Forums: [Uploading File via HTTP Post from VBA does not work](https://archive.ph/POkdm#selection-1025.0-1025.51)
- [WinHttp.WinHttpRequest adding to the content-type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35641883/12597)
- MSDN Forums: [How do I prevent WinHttpRequest from automatically appending Charset=UTF-8 to ContentType?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/52fca0ca-858d-4c9a-9daa-e693a290f40d/how-do-i-prevent-winhttprequest-from-automatically-appending-charsetutf8-to-contenttype?forum=windowscompatibility)
- Dart-lang: [Remove charset from "Content-Type" header #184](https://github.com/dart-lang/http/issues/184)